# Asp.net core 3.1 Authorization not working!!! Always return 401 even when token is provided

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am basically following the instruction on this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s2zJ_g-iQvg&ab_channel=CodAffection my problem is that I am using ASP.NET CORE while he is using ASP.NET CORE 2.2. And for some reason my api calls allways return 401 despite me having change only some line of code to make it compatible with ASP.NET CORE 2.2.

I want to make API calls when the user is login I am using ASP.NET CORE 3.1. I have made a login function which works. When I make an API call with postman the login function returns a token. However when I call another route (clients) and provided the bearer token I get a 401 error. I have searched for days but am unable to solve the problem. I have tried many different tutorials but I keep having the same problem. Thank you for your help.

```
[HttpPost, Route("login")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginModel user)
{
    var userFromDb = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(user.UserName);
    if (user != null &&  true)//await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, user.Password))
    {
        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                new Claim("UserID", "1")
            }),
            Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1),
            SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superlongKeyWithALotOfWordsToMakeItMoreSecureWhichIsGoodThankYouForReadingMySecretKey@45")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
        };
        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var securityToken = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var token = tokenHandler.WriteToken(securityToken);
        return Ok(new { token });
    }
    else 
    {
        return Unauthorized();
    }

}
```

Here is what my startup file looks like

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<ApplicationSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("AppSettings")); 
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddTransient<DatabaseMigrator>();
        services.AddDbContext<erp_colombiaDbContext>(options => options.UseMySql(
                 Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"),
                 optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(DesignTimeDbContextFactory).Assembly.FullName)));
        services.TryAddScoped<UserManager<Employee>>();
        services.TryAddScoped<SignInManager<Employee>>();

        services.AddIdentityCore<Employee>(options => 
            options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false
        ).AddEntityFrameworkStores<erp_colombiaDbContext>();

        //Jwt Authentication

        var key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superlongKeyWithALotOfWordsToMakeItMoreSecureWhichIsGoodThankYouForReadingMySecretKey@45");//Configuration["AppSettings:Secret"].ToString());

        services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
            options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
            options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
            options.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
        });

        services.AddCors();

        //Jwt Authentication

        services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
        {
            x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
            x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(key),
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };
        });

        // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
        services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
        });

        services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        if (!env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        }

        app.UseRouting();

        // global cors policy
        app.UseCors(x => x
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader());


        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            // To learn more about options for serving an Angular SPA from ASP.NET Core,
            // see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=864501

            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

and here is part of my appSettings.json setings.

```
  "AppSettings": {
    "Secret": "superlongKeyWithALotOfWordsToMakeItMoreSecureWhichIsGoodThankYouForReadingMySecretKey@45",
    "ClientURL": "https://localhost:44344"
  },
```

Here is the other route (clients)

```
// GET api/clients
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public IEnumerable<ClientViewModel> Get()
{
    ClientViewModel clientViewModel;
    List<ClientViewModel> listClientViewModels = new List<ClientViewModel>();

    var clients = Task.Run(async () => await _clientService.GetAllClients()).Result;

    foreach (var client in clients) 
    {
        clientViewModel = new ClientViewModel();
        clientViewModel.ClientId = client.ClientId;
        clientViewModel.Active = client.Active;
        clientViewModel.Address = client.Address;
        clientViewModel.City = client.City;
        clientViewModel.ClienteName = client.ClienteName;
        clientViewModel.ComercialEmployeeId = client.ComercialEmployeeId;
        clientViewModel.Confirmed = client.Confirmed;
        clientViewModel.CountryId = client.CountryId;
        clientViewModel.CreationDate = client.CreationDate;
        clientViewModel.DANE = client.DANE;
        clientViewModel.Department = client.Department;
        clientViewModel.ElectronicBillingEmail = client.ElectronicBillingEmail;
        clientViewModel.Eliminated = client.Eliminated;
        clientViewModel.NIT = client.NIT;
        clientViewModel.PostalCode = client.PostalCode;
        clientViewModel.Phone = client.Phone;

        listClientViewModels.Add(clientViewModel);
    }

    return listClientViewModels;
}
```

Here is how I add the token in postman.

[image: Image of postman when making call with token]

Comment: Try adding `.AddJwtBearer(x => { x.IncludeErrorDetails = true;` see if you get some additional error details.  You should probably change the ClockSkew to `TimeSpan.FromMinute(5)`, maybe they're off enough that it's not validating.  And for security reasons, you should definintely set `RequireSignedTokens = true,`    [Critical vulnerabilities in JSON Web Token](https://auth0.com/blog/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/)

Comment: How are you sending the bearer token in POSTMAN?

Comment: I have added x.IncludeErrorDetails = true; where can I see the details? I have tried in postman in headers but I do not see any aditional error information. Thank you @ErikPhilips

Comment: @ErikPhilips I have added a image of how I use the bearer token in POSTMAN.

Comment: This is a postman call to your *locally running code*?  It doesn't look like it.  You won't get error information on deployed release code.

Comment: @ErikPhilips how can I tell if code is running locally? I am using localhost:myport if that is your question? In my visual studio code 2019 it says that it is in debug mode in the drop down.

Comment: please add app.UseAuthorization(); before endpoints and after routing and add app.UseAuthentication(); before routing

Comment: @avikalb that won't fix the problem.

Comment: @avikalb I have tried but it dosent work sandly. But thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out I had this code that overwrite the [Authorize] attribute.

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class AuthorizeAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var user = (User)context.HttpContext.Items["User"];
        if (user == null)
        {
            // not logged in
            context.Result = new JsonResult(new { message = "Unauthorized" }) { StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized };
        }
    }
}
```

I removed it and now it work I dont understand why the code was there. Sorry, for my question.

Answer (score 2):

fix your startup, add before app.UseEndpoints

```
            ....
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
             .....
```

Comment: I have added the two lines you have suggested in front of app.UseEnpoints but I am still getting a 401 when I make a call to my clients enpoint. :(

Comment: Can you post the Clients API  pls?

Comment: Yes I have Added the Clients route in my question.

Comment: Neither of these are required for JWT to work correctly.

Comment: Thank you ! I had teh same problem and app.UseAuthentication(); fixed me the problem

Answer (score 0):

Add the options.Events to your AddJwtBearer:

```
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
  options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
  {
    OnAuthenticationFailed = c =>
    {
      // break point here
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    },
  };
});
```

Then you'll get some context.exception:

(right-click image, open in new window/tab)

[image]

You should **never do this on asp.net**

```
// Task.Run is a no no
Task.Run(async () => await _clientService.GetAllClients()).Result;
```

You're using locking up 2 threads at the same time for no benefit.

Instead:

```
// GET api/clients
[HttpGet]
[Authorize]
public Task<IEnumerable<ClientViewModel>> Get()
```

and

```
var clients = await _clientService.GetAllClients();
```

Comment: Thank you for you information about the Task.run. I used the task.run beacause I had issus with making the call the the api method with Angular but that is okey I will figure it out a other time. When it comes to the return Task.Completed task the breakpoint only hits when the app is started but it does not hit when I call the clients api method.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `[Authorize]` attribute?

Comment: OMG move your `AddMvc()` to after the `AddSpaStaticFiles()`

Comment: When I remove the [Authorize] the api call works to clients. When I move AddMvC after addSpaStaticFiles nothing change I still get 401 when I make a call to get clients even with the token key.

Answer (score 0):

For .Net Core you need to use a authorization provider like Identity Server:

https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Does IdentityServer4 work with Angular as well?

Comment: You can use OAuth and OIDC with Angular so yes

Comment: Ok thank you for the infromation I will look for a tutoriel online. If it work I will approve your answer. I may take me a few days doe.